# Java insertion sort algorithm

Tags: java, sorting

I have this code and it works. It does what I wanted to do. When the user inputs a number, the program immediately makes the sort, putting the number in the first position. But to me it's a little bit complicated. I'm still a beginner. I understand what it does but is there a better way to do it. An easier way? Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class practice {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] num = new int[10];
        int n = 0, l = 0, t = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
            System.out.print("Número: ");
            n = input.nextInt();
            l = 0;

            while(num[l] < n && l < i){
                l = l + 1;
            }
            t = i;
            while(t > l){
                num[t] = num[t - 1];
                t = t - 1;
            }
            num[l] = n;
            for(int temp : num){
                System.out.print(temp + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is always a _better_, _cleaner_ and _easier_ way to do it. But as long as it is working, it's fine

Comment: This should be on codereview.SE.

Comment: I think if you use a kind of a `List` like `ArrayList` it can be better -As a lesson of Data-Structures- ;).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that I can think of is:

```
int[] arra = {1,5,7,2,9,2};
Arrays.sort(arra);
```

Or we can try something like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class practice {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] num = new int[10];
        int n,j = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
            System.out.print("Número: ");
            n = input.nextInt();
            j = i;
            while (j > 0 && num[j - 1] > n) {
                num[j] = num[j - 1];
                j--;
            }
            num[j] = n;

            for(int temp : num){
                System.out.print(temp + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `Arrays.sort()` a variation of quicksort?

Comment: @seanhodges I also think this is similar but as OP wants, this  is an easier way ;).